# Set properties of a control from one location not as clear text

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background information:**
Our application is controlling a machine.
Different machine parts can be started and stopped by means of buttons on the screen.
We have made our own buttons to get the right look and feel. This button is called HMIButton and derives from Control:

```
public class HMIButton : Control
```

One property of this button is called UserLevel and another RequiredUserLevel.
In the OnMouseDown event we cancel the event in case the current user level (globally set in the application) 
is not sufficient compared to the required user level for the respective button:

```
if (_userLevel < _requiredUserLevel)
{ 
    return; //Cancel mouse down event
}
```

So far the RequiredUserLevel has been set from the designer in Visual Studio for each button at design time.
The forms in the application where these buttons are located are reused across several applications for different customers.

**The issue is:**
If a customer wants the RequiredUserLevel for a certain button to be something else than our standard,
we have to change this in our "template", and ship this "special" version to him.

What we would like is the ability to have the definitions of RequiredUserLevel somewhere central, e.g. in a .resx file,
so we can modify this for each button individually for each customer.

We don't mind having to compile with this file every time a RequiredUserLevel must be changed,
we just don't want the RequiredUserLevel to be hard coded in the designer file of each form where a button is used.

**What we have considered:**
We have considered to e.g. use a .resx file with an entry for each button, and then set the property of the buttons at run time
with the values from the .resx file.
The problem here would be that anyone could just modify the .resx file on the target system, and then e.g. change the RequiredUserLevel to 0 of all button.
We do not require a bullet proof protection, but at least it should not be possible to just modify the values as clear text.
Again, a solution where the application must be recompiled would be OK, where everything is compiled into the .exe itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Editing a .resx file only makes sense on your machine, you don't ship it to your customer.   You don't appear to have a real problem.

Comment: OK, missed that. Would you think using a .resx file makes sense in my case, or would it be a misuse of these?

Comment: I would just provide a simple text file, name of the control and an integer.  You only have to add a GetUserLevel(YourButton ctl) method to make it effective.  Gives the customer full control over what they want to customize, you don't have to be involved at all.  Deploy in the same directory as the EXE so that only a user with admin privileges can edit it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the customer to be able to edit the stuff, only the programmer of the application.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

If you make the RequiredUserLevel a property you should be able to bind it to a Application Scope Setting. Any client who needs different values can change the settings file of their installation.

### Solution 2

Reconsider the idea of a resource file inside your project that holds all the requireduserlevel values. With a modern source control system it would be relatively trivial to track and update branches with the custom values for each client.

### Solution 3

Implement a custom plugin dll whose source code is trivial and merely includes the resource file holding the requireduserlevel values. Your application will look for that dll on start up. Only the administrators at your clients can create that dll. Giving out the sources for that plugin would not compromise the IP for your program.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't the user be able to modify this settings file on the target machine?

Comment: @JohnSaps only if he has write permissions inside the application folder